# order by month oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make a simple query to find the average car sales per month from a table called "salestransaction".

My code:

```
    select to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MON') as mnth, count(*) / 2 as Average_Car_Sales
    from salestransaction st
    group by to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MON')
    order by to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MON');
```

My order by month is not outputting the correct order.
What can I do to make it output by month? starting from JAN - DEC?

Thank you.

Comment: Would that be the average car sales per month, by day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy approach is to add month number to group by, then order by this field:

```
select to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MON') as mnth, 
       count(*) / 2 as Average_Car_Sales
from salestransaction st
group by EXTRACT(month FROM st.dateofsale),
         to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MON')
order by EXTRACT(month FROM st.dateofsale);
```

If you try to order without aggregate function or without adding month number in group by expression then you will get `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error

To avoid Extract you can use to_char with MM pattern:

```
select to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MON') as mnth, 
       count(*) / 2 as Average_Car_Sales
from salestransaction st
group by to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MM'),
         to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MON')
order by to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MM');
```

Comment: I haven't been taught about the extract function. Any other ways of doing it if I were to use to_char ?

Comment: just added to answer.

Comment: That seems to work, but I don't understand why exactly. Isn't my first attempt the same? I was grouping it by `to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MON)`.. what's the different with `MON` and `MM`?

Comment: as you know, `to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MON')` returns a 3 letters string representation, 'DEC' is < than 'NOV'. Then you should sort by numbers instead by letters. '12' > '11'. Also, to include expression in order by, this expression should appear in group by ( or be enclosed in aggregate function as @GordonLinoff has been suggest to you).

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation:

```
order by min(st.dateofsale);
```

That is, just pull a value out for each group and use that for the ordering.

If you have data from multiple years, the above might not work.  Instead:

```
order by min(extract(month from st.dateofsale))
```

Comment: I haven't been taught about the extract function. Any other ways of doing it if I were to use to_char ?

Comment: You can use `min(to_char(st.dateofsale, 'MM'))`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you order them according to the month name in this case, december comes before january. You need to get their numeric values.
Here is an example from oracle documantation:

SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM order_date) "Month",

COUNT(order_date) "No. of Orders"

FROM orders

GROUP BY EXTRACT(month FROM order_date)

ORDER BY EXTRACT(month FROM order_date)

You can check it from this link for more detailed information:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm